# Optional Data Feed on the EVM, what does it mean?

Tags: private-blockchain, evm, data-feeds

I am trying to understand the idea of optional data feed for EVM in the accounting field especially. I usually read that you can use two fields with the first field being a domain to register and the second field being the IP address to register it to. Would it be possible to register anything else than a domain? to be more specific, do you know what it would look like in accounting when it comes to adding account to the blockchain, confirming transaction, etc...

thank you